The Archive COMMAND github "history"
Here is the link on HOW TO ARCHIVE a repo
https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/archiving-a-github-repository/archiving-repositories
My question is not about "how to"
I am trying to figure out how to see the HISTORY (aka, "who" (or what service-account) performed the archive.
This normal repo history shows me "file changes".
But not (or I am not privileged enough to see) the history for the ARCHIVE operation.
Where do I see the history of these kind of actions?
......
Append:
When I look under the repo "Activity".
/my-repo-name/activity
the dropdown for 'types' of activity are:
"All activity"
"Direct pushes"
"Pull request merges"
"Merge queue merges"
"Force pushes"
"Branch creations"
"Branch deletions"

And no "red zone" types.

Why am I getting downvoted?  A legit question?  With an actual answer?  Figuring out the history of an archive operation .. so I can figure out who did it?  I don't know where this kind of history is stored.

After I unarchived the repo, the repo is very active/busy, so I cannot just look at "last 10 things that happened".  And the action occurred .. the day before a major holiday, thus when it occurred, I was just trying to get it back to unarchive before the day ended.

Thanks to those who upvoted the question to get me back to (at least) zero.  I still have no idea why it was downvoted in the first place.

You can check the audit logs for your organization to see who archived a repository: https://github.com/organizations/YOURORGANIZATION/settings/audit-log?q=action%3Arepo.archived shows all "repo archived" events.
If you have GitHub Enterprise Cloud, you can also use an API for this.
Notice that you need to be an organization owner to access audit logs.

Thank you.  I currently do not have these permissions, but now I know which permissions I don't have !           Appreciate you  looking at my (downvoted for whatever reason) question.       It might take a day to get permissions, but I'll come back here to revisit. (for marking "the" answer)
